How to automate parted answers file
We want to give an answers file to parted command
First here is a manual example that works fine on our RedHat 7.9 server:
parted /dev/sda  resizepart 3 100%
Error: The backup GPT table is not at the end of the disk, as it should be.  This might mean that another operating system believes the disk is smaller.  Fix, by moving the backup to the end (and removing the old backup)?
parted: invalid token: 3    <-- first answer
Fix/Ignore/Cancel? Fix  <-- second answer
Warning: Not all of the space available to /dev/sda appears to be used, you can fix the GPT to use all of the space (an extra 167772160 blocks) or continue with the current setting?
Fix/Ignore? Fix <-- third answer
Partition number? 3  <-- fourth answer
End?  [73.0GB]?  <-- last empty answer "\n"
Information: You may need to update /etc/fstab.

So we try the following with echo (to automate the process)
echo -e "3\nFix\nFix\n3\n" | parted /dev/sda  resizepart 3 100%
Error: The backup GPT table is not at the end of the disk, as it should be.  This might mean that another operating system believes the disk is smaller.  Fix, by moving the backup to the end (and removing the old backup)?
Warning: Not all of the space available to /dev/sda appears to be used, you can fix the GPT to use all of the space (an extra 167772160 blocks) or continue with the current setting?
Error: Unable to satisfy all constraints on the partition.
Error: Can't have overlapping partitions.

but echo isn't working to give the right answers to the parted command .
We can't use the expect command since this command not installed on our Redhat servers (and we can't install it because of security concerns).
Any idea about how to gives parted the answers? Or maybe how to use parted -s?
parted --help
Usage: parted [OPTION]... [DEVICE [COMMAND [PARAMETERS]...]...]
Apply COMMANDs with PARAMETERS to DEVICE.  If no COMMAND(s) are given, run in
interactive mode.

OPTIONs:
  -h, --help                      displays this help message
  -l, --list                      lists partition layout on all block devices
  -m, --machine                   displays machine parseable output
  -s, --script                    never prompts for user intervention
  -v, --version                   displays the version
  -a, --align=[none|cyl|min|opt]  alignment for new partitions

We did also (without help):
parted -s /dev/sda resizepart 3 100% 3 Fix Fix 3 \n
Error: The backup GPT table is not at the end of the disk, as it should be.  This might mean that another operating system believes the disk is smaller.  Fix, by moving the backup to the end (and removing the old backup)?
Warning: Not all of the space available to /dev/sda appears to be used, you can fix the GPT to use all of the space (an extra 167772160 blocks) or continue with the current setting?
Error: Unable to satisfy all constraints on the partition.
Error: Can't have overlapping partitions.


so just parted -s?

how? , I mean how to use it with all my parameters ?

parted -s /dev/sda  resizepart 3 100% , see parted --help Also parted -f, see parted --help

about parted -s /dev/sda  resizepart 3 100% , I understand but where to put all the answers parameters as --> 3 Fix Fix  3  \n

nowhere, it doesn't ask you anymore, it's in the arguments. My parted also has --fix, seems like yours doesn't. So this optino might be not viable.

Tangentially, while echo -e works as long as you are sure you are running Bash, it's ugly and brittle. The more elegant, portable, and robust solution is to use printf.

One obvious problem is that your script doesn't include the final lone \n but I guess fixing that won't help.
